# What is solution for fetching data from database using JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a database that has table call users and wants to print email and city fields from the database with the get method using JSON.

Below is my HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>show info</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="button">
    <input type="submit" class="button" id="show" value="show profile">
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="show.js"></script>

</html>
```

here is my JavaScript code:

```js
function shows() {
  fetch("/profile", {
      method: "get",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      response.json().then(function(json) {
        alert("show profile successfully");
      })
    })
}
show.addEventListener("click", shows);
```

Comment: Share your API response for `/profile` endpoint. so it will be easy to help you

Comment: How are you supposed to handle the click event, if you have no link between the event handler and the event source (i.e. button). Neither do you have an `onclick` event in your button element nor a `.addEventListener` in your JS code.

Answer (score 1):

```
async function fetchUserData() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("/profile", {
      method: "get",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });

    const user = await response.json();
    console.log(user);

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```